# Maintaining and supporting container base images

Tags: docker, containers

We are growing company with most of our infrastructure based on containers. Right now each dev group manages its own base images (frameworks and etc.) but in near future it looks like be a management nightmare. It feels that there must be some centralized solution to manage all the updates, vulnerabilities monitoring and etc. as we are less interested in our devs doing this work and more concentrate on their primary responsibilities.

Our primary concern how to take care of

- updating images with development frameworks (python, node.js)
- patch vulnerabilities once discovered and updates provided
- all this at scale

To focus the question, we at the company do not want to manage all the base and framework layers but only concentrate on our application layers that we have created.

**UPDATE:**

We do not change framework and base images but only upper layer are changed as they are our actual applications. The problem with upstream if for example with `Python` image:

- Who is responsible for updating its OS layer?
- Who is responsible for updating its Python (framework) layer?
- Who can ensure that the OS layer is based on upstream or any other standard OS layer?

In many cases, framework layer maintainer cares about the framework and less for OS.

We are event thinking to outsource to 3rd party company which will do this maintenance and support for us.

Appreciate your comments/thoughts on this.

Comment: This is pretty broad and solutions are going to differ between organizations. How many base images are you talking about? What are you customizing in the base images that are different from the upstream official images? The first two points are mostly taken care of by using official images. Updating for patches and vulnerabilities then just becomes updating `FROM` image (similar to how you might update a Node.js or Python dependency in the application).

Comment: I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are searching for is an enterprise-grade registry.

You should check Docker Trusted Registry, with Docker EE. It would take care of most the things you need.

https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/dtr/2.0/

Comment: How does this address e.g. the OP's concerns around security patching?

Comment: Docker Trusted Registry does have CVE detection. I figured it might help.

BTW I'm not affiliated with Docker in anyway.
And also note that the OP's question is very broad. I'm just trying to give some solutions.

Comment: The problem with DTR is that we still need to do all the updates to the base images internally and that's what we try to evade.

Comment: Ok I see, what you actually want is not a software but a company/service managing all your images. Except PaaS providers (even if it's not really what you are searching), I don't see any solution.